# How to auto replace tikzpicture by includegraphics using TikZ external?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way using e.g. the `external` TikZ library to produce, from a master LaTeX document, another LaTeX source where each `tikzpicture` environment is replaced by the appropriate `includegraphics` command?

This can be painful to do by hand in a document which contains many such environments.

Example master document `x.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{...}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
  ...
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{B}
  \end{figure}
  ...
\end{document}
```

desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
  ...
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{x-figure0}
    \caption{A}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{x-figure1}
    \caption{B}
  \end{figure}
  ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more or less what `external` library does. When the figure doesn't exist, it creates a pdf file which is used in later compilations.

Comment: Then how can I get the `.tex` that `external` generates? I need to replace pictures in TikZ and pgfplots by the generated PDF images in the `.tex`, i.e. I would like to get automatically a LaTeX document with no PGF/TikZ code. This is for a submission to arxiv, which does not seem to support correctly pgfplots.

Answer (score 5):

All about `externalization` is explained is section "50 Externalization Library" and how to send a tex file with `tikzpictures` without using `tikz` is explained in section "50.5 Using External Graphics Without pgf Installed". So, please read these pages. What follows is just a short recipe without to many details. The code has been borrowed from `pgfmanual`.

The original file contains `tikzpictures` which are externalizated. It load `tikz` and `external` library. With command `\tikzexternalize`, all `tikzpictures` are extracted and processed. For a `main.tex` file several `main-figureX.pdf` (and some `.dpth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);.
Furthermore, we might want to draw \tikz[baseline]\draw (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{document}
```

Once all figures are correct. Preamble is changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

`tikz` package and `external` library are not used any more and are replaced by `graphicx` and `tikzexternal` packages (`tikzexternal.sty` is in folder `latex/pgf/utilities/tikzexternal.sty` and you must copy it to your working folder).

Next run will load `.pdf` figures instead of generating them.