# Converting pgfplots usage to includegraphics (cannot use -shell-escape)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shell-escape, arxiv

I am uploading a paper to arxiv, which does not allow the use of shell-escape.

Currently my paper uses pgfplots as in the following MWE:

```
temp.tex
----------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
      \draw plot function{x*x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
      \draw plot function{sqrt(x)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile with the following, everything works fine:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape temp.tex
```

**How can I create the figures and include them in my document without using shell-escape?** Ideally, I would run some script to produce fig1.pdf and fig2.pdf, then replace the MWE above with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{fig1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{fig2}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could externalize the tikzpictures on your own computer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics) and you'll get the images as pdfs which you can upload to arxiv

Comment: Can you modify `temp.tex` to have `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` and remove the `figure` environments, and then have a different `.tex` file with e.g. `\includegraphics[page=1]{temp}`?

Comment: @samcarter, thanks, that looks like it should be what I want -- I'll try it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I'm not sure exactly what these instructions do, but I can try to look into that next.

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (1,1); \end{tikzpicture} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,2) -- (2,0); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}` will produce a 2 page PDF, one page per `tikzpicture`, where each page is exactly the size of the `tikzpicture`. The `page` option for `includegraphics` does exactly what you think: it determines which page of a multi-page PDF is included.

Comment: I wonder where the shell escape comes from, if not using externalize?  FPU driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many possible solutions, but it was relatively easy for me to use the solution linked by samcarter: [Script to automate externalizing TikZ graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics)

Afterwards, a friend pointed me to the following answer which seems to do the conversion automatically: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271475/5097